# Submit form using FormData and render form with validation errors

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, form-data

I have a form in a Rails application that creates a new `Car` record. Because I want the user to be able to select and upload image files and then submit them with the form, I am going to use the HTML5 FormData object to submit the data on form submit, with Coffeescript like so:

```
filesArray = new Array()

$(document).on 'change', '.file-fields .file-field', () ->

    if @files and @files[0]

        file = @files[0]
        imageType = /image.*/

        if file.type.match(imageType)

            filesArray.push(file)

    return

$(document).on 'submit', '#car-form', (e) ->

    e.preventDefault()

    formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("car-form"))
    i = 0

    while i < filesArray.length
        file = filesArray[i]
        formData.append "photos[]", file, file.name
        i++

    $.ajax '/cars',
        type: "POST"
        data: formData
        processData: false
        contentType: false

    return
```

But I want the form to still behave as if it is being submitted synchronously, so that Rails performs the validations and renders the form with error messages if validations fail. Currently, my `CarsController` has a `create` action like this:

```
def create

    @car = current_user.cars.build(car_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @car.save

        format.html { redirect_to @car, notice: 'Car was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @car }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @car.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I am using FormData to submit images instead of sending directly via the form so that I can handle image previews.

When I submit the form it, the parameters are passed to the `CarsController#create` action and some `before_action` filters are triggered. But nothing happens on the form, it is not reloaded and validations do not appear.

```
Processing by CarsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", ...
  Rendered cars/_form.html.erb (60.8ms)
  Rendered cars/new.html.erb within layouts/application (62.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 746ms (Views: 640.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)
```

How should I setup the form, controller, and Javascript so that my form will behave as if submitted synchronously with validation errors for incorrect data?

Comment: Just on a side note. Some IE versions have a bug (mine for example; IE10/11 region Dutch). `file.type` returns an empty string on images. Just to let you know.

Comment: You don't need an Ajax request to send files. Just set the `enctype` of your form to `multipart/form-data` and the `method` to `post`. Set the attribute `multiple` on the file input.

Comment: I am implementing image previews on my form. So I want to store the images that the user selects in an array and then send that array with the rest of the form data, when the user submits the form.

Comment: I get it. That's nice. I love that about HTML5. What happens now when you submit your ajax, what is returned?

Comment: I updated the question with the server logs. When I submit the form it does not appear to reload anything, but the log says that `cars/_form.html.erb` and `cars/new.html.erb` are rendered, so I think they might be rendered asynchronously. But there are no validations.

Comment: I don't really know Ruby, but shouldn't you let it output some HTML and than edit it. Ajax, if successful, returns the request body, not a new page, changing the fact that it load synchronously or not doesn't matter. You need to parse that request body.

Answer (score 1):

Sample form:

```
   <form class="file-fields" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <input class="file-field" type="file" multiple />
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
   </form>
```

CoffeeScript:

```
$(document).on 'submit', '#car-form', (e) ->

    fileInput = $('.file-fields .file-field')[0]
    for i = 0 i < fileInput.length i++
        file = @files[i]
        imageType = /image.*/

        if !file.type.match(imageType)
            return false

    return true
```

This checks if the input has images. If one isn't correct fail the submit. Else submit and let Rails take over.